# In PHP 5.6, does mbstring.encoding_translation serve any purpose anymore?

Tags: php, php-5.6, mbstring

In PHP 5.6 the following configuration variables have been deprecated:

```
mbstring.internal_encoding
mbstring.http_input
mbstring.http_output
```

Instead we are told that PHP 5.6 and later users should leave these empty and set default_charset instead. Now, my understand of `mbstring.encoding_translation` is that it turns on conversion of http POST data from `mbstring.http_input` to `mbstring.internal_encoding`

But if we use a single variable for both of these, then we get conversion of http POST data from `default_charset` to... `default_charset`? That's a no-op. So is there any purpose to `mbstring.encoding_translation` anymore?

Answer (score 0):

My **guess** is that a website usually expects data to be received in the same encoding as used for output. So if a website uses UTF-8, it expects data to be sent to it in UTF-8 as well.

So if you want your website to use another encoding, you now only have to adjust [`default_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) and from a PHP configuration point of view, you are done. PHP then properly sets `Content-Type` to let the client (browser) know.